# Битрикс и псевдо мультидоменность

Tags: битрикс

Есть главный сайт mysite.ru. Заказчик поставил задачу разбить сайт на под домены msk.site.ru, spb.site.ru, etc.site.ru ... Меняться будет только шапка. Вопрос : сталкивались ли вы с такой задачей и как решили? Symlink? .htaccess? Зеркалирование?

Comment: Читайте документацию раздел "Многосайтовость" есть даже отдельный курс (не поверите первые сслыки по запросу "битрикс многосайтовость").

Comment: По поводу многосайтовости могу еще порекомендовать [Решение для регионов](http://moskva.av-promo.ru/modules/aristov.vregions/) Очень крутая штука, плюс можно управлять сео, и даже ценами для каждого региона

Comment: Очень похоже на рекламу. Вы имеете какое-то отношение к продвигаемому по ссылке сайту? У нас очень не любят когда аккаунты-однодневки начинают SEO-ссылки постить, можно и минусов получить в репутацию.

Comment: Ну вообще-то это не реклама, в прошлом году очень помогло это решение, и именно для сео использовали. Получалось, что на каждый регион, который определялся у пользователя - мы получали поддомен с полной копией сайта, плюс открывали магазин в Питере и там, соответственно, нужно было ставить ценники меньше, чем в Москве - вот эта, как вы тут минусуете, реклама мне реально помогла, надеюсь кому-то тоже поможет, пусть и заминусуете.

Я считаю каммент в самую точку! и решение тоже! в итоге получились именно псевдо домены с отдельными robots и sitemap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Технически многосайтовая версия продукта может быть реализована в двух конфигурационных режимах:

- Многосайтовость на одном домене. (Старое название: Многосайтовость по первому способу.) Продукт и все сайты работают под управлением одной копии веб-сервера Apache.
- Многосайтовость на разных доменах. (Старое название: Многосайтовость по второму способу.) Каждый сайт работает под управлением отдельной копии веб-сервера Apache или отдельного виртуального веб-сервера.
  Конфигурирование сайтов

**Многосайтовость на одном домене**

Принципиальная необходимость для многосайтовости на одном домене - разделение сайтов по подкаталогам, так, чтобы структура файлов не пересекалась. Каждый сайт должен быть размещен в отдельном подкаталоге внутри корневого каталога.

При этом возможно как создание равнозначных папок в структуре корневого каталога, так и создание папок второго сайта внутри директории первого сайта. То есть, допустимы комбинации как вида:

```
/www/s1/ - первый сайт,
/www/s2/ - второй сайт.
```

Так и комбинации вида:

```
/www/s1/ - первый сайт,
/www/s1/s2 – второй сайт.
```

При настройке многосайтовости на одном домене мы располагаем одним веб-сервером Apache, DocumentRoot которого настроен на каталог /home/www/allsites.

Установим программный продукт «1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом» в этот каталог.

Каждый сайт в первом способе конфигурации должен быть размещен в отдельном подкаталоге внутри единого каталога, например:

```
/home/www/allsites/s1/
/home/www/allsites/s2/
```

Имена каталогов s1, s2 можно выбирать любыми, например, shop и company, или en и de соответственно. Возможен так же вариант, когда один из сайтов располагается в корневом каталоге (например, /home/www/allsites/), а второй сайт в подкаталоге (например, /home/www/allsites/s2/).

Настройка сайтов выполняется в Административном разделе системы (Настройки > Настройки продукта > Сайты > Список сайтов).

Выбираем "Изменить" параметры сайта №1 и указываем в них:

```
Название: site1
Доменное имя: оставить пустым
Папка сайта: /s1/
Название сайта: Корпоративный сайт компании "Название компании"
URL сервера:www.site1.com/s1
Путь к корневой папке веб-сервера для этого сайта: оставить пустым
```

В параметре Папка сайта необходимо указывать путь относительно корня к каталогу в котором расположена публичная часть сайта. А Путь к корневой папке веб-сервера для этого сайта не используется в данном способе настройки многосайтовости и должен быть пустым для всех сайтов.

Аналогично настроим параметры сайта №2:

```
Название: site2
Доменное имя: оставить пустым
Папка сайта: /s2/
Название сайта: Интернет-магазин компании "Название компании"
URL сервера:www.site1.com/s2
Путь к корневой папке веб-сервера для этого сайта: оставить пустым
```

**Многосайтовость на разных доменах**

Для работы многосайтовости на разных доменах нам потребуется произвести настройку программного продукта. Настройку веб-сервера Apache, как и в случае с многосайтовостью на одном домене, должна произвести хостинговая компания.

Будем использовать для примера конфигурацию из двух сайтов:

```
www.site1.com - корпоративный сайт компании
www.site2.com - интернет-магазин компании
```

Каждый сайт надо разместить в соответствующем каталоге, например:

```
/home/www/site1/
/home/www/site2/
```

Продукт устанавливается в один из сайтов. Чтобы ядро могло работать для обоих сайтов, необходимо создать символьные ссылки для сайта, в котором нет установленного ядра. Ссылки потребуются для папок /bitrix, /local и /upload. Эти папки являются общими для обоих сайтов, такова особенность архитектуры.

Ссылки можно создать двумя способами. Первый - классический, который рекомендовался компанией с самого начала. Второй - более поздний, считается более "красивым и изящным". В нем отсутствует шаг создания отдельной папки и переноса в нее ядра системы.

Первый вариант:

1. установите программный продукт "1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом"
   сначала в каталог первого сайта `/home/www/site1/`
2. создайте каталог `/home/www/shared/`, в котором будут располагаться
   общие для всех сайтов файлы:

   `mkdir /home/www/shared`
3. перенесите весь каталог `/home/www/site1/bitrix/` в
   `/home/www/shared/bitrix/`:

   `mv /home/www/site1/bitrix /home/www/shared/bitrix`
4. перенесите весь каталог `/home/www/site1/upload/` в
   `/home/www/shared/upload/`:

   `mv /home/www/site1/upload /home/www/shared/upload`
5. перенесите весь каталог `/home/www/site1/local/` в
   `/home/www/shared/local/`:

   `mv /home/www/site1/local /home/www/shared/local`
6. создайте символическую связь для каталога /bitrix/ в каждом из
   сайтов:

   ```
   ln -s /home/www/shared/bitrix /home/www/site1/
   ln -s /home/www/shared/upload /home/www/site1/
   ln -s /home/www/shared/local /home/www/site1/
   ln -s /home/www/shared/bitrix /home/www/site2/
   ln -s /home/www/shared/upload /home/www/site2/
   ln -s /home/www/shared/local /home/www/site2/
   ```
7. убедитесь, что веб-сервер (Apache, IIS) имеет право на запись в
   каталог /home/www/shared/ (это необходимо будет для работы системы
   обновлений и загрузки графических файлов)
8. разместите публичную часть второго сайта в каталог `/home/www/site2/`

При настройке многосайтовой конфигурации на UNIX, можно воспользоваться программным методом создания символьных ссылок:

```
<?
symlink("/virt/homes/forinsured/bitrix", "/virt/homes/forinsured/htdocs/bitrix");
symlink("/virt/homes/forinsured/upload", "/virt/homes/forinsured/htdocs/upload");
symlink("/virt/homes/forinsured/local", "/virt/homes/forinsured/htdocs/local");
?>
```

Второй вариант. В нем символьные ссылки создаются непосредственно в папке второго сайта.

1. Установите программный продукт «1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом» сначала в каталог первого сайта `/home/www/site1/`
2. Создайте в корневой папке второго сайта (`/home/www/site2/`) скрипт, например, под именем `symlink.php`:

```html
<html>
<head><title>Создание ссылок на папки bitrix, local и upload</title></head>
<body>
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
@ini_set("display_errors",1);

if ($_POST['path'])
   $path = rtrim($_POST['path'],"/\\");
else
   $path = '../site1/www';

if ($_POST['create'])
{
   if (preg_match("#^/#",$path))
      $full_path = $path;
   else
      $full_path = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$path);

   if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bitrix"))
      $strError = "В текущей папке уже существует папка bitrix";
   elseif (is_dir($full_path))
   {
      if (is_dir($full_path."/bitrix"))
      {
         if (symlink($path."/bitrix",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bitrix"))
         {
            if (symlink($path."/upload",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload"))
             {
               if (symlink($path."/local",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/local"))
                  echo "Символические ссылки удачно созданы";
               else
               $strError = 'Не удалось создать ссылку на папку local, обратитесь к администратору сервера';
              }
           else
           $strError = 'Не удалось создать ссылку на папку upload, обратитесь к администратору сервера';
          }
          else
          $strError = 'Не удалось создать ссылку на папку bitrix, обратитесь к администратору сервера';           
      }
      else
         $strError = 'Указанный путь не содержит папку bitrix';
   }
   else
      $strError = 'Неверно указан путь или ошибка прав доступа';
   
   if ($strError)
      echo ''.$strError.'
Исходный путь: '.$full_path;
}
?>
<form method=post>
Путь к папке, содержащей папки bitrix, local и upload: <input name=path  value="<?=htmlspecialchars($path)?>"><br>
<input type=submit value='Создать' name=create>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

3. Запустите скрипт и укажите путь к корневой папке первого сайта, в нашем случае `/home/www/site1/`.
4. После того как символьные ссылки созданы, наберите в адресной строке браузера `site1/bitrix/admin`. Откроется панель авторизации.
5. Введите данные администратора, которые указывали при установке продукта на первый сайт, и попадете в административную панель «1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом».

После завершения работы скрипта наличие символических ссылок на папки `/bitrix, /local и /upload` в папке второго сайта можно проверить по появлению одноименных папок.

Настройка сайтов выполняется в административном разделе системы на странице Настройки > Настройки продукта > Сайты > Список сайтов.

В строке первого сайта (www.site1.com), в колонке действий выбираем команду Изменить и указываем в них:

```
Название: site1
Доменное имя:site1.com
Папка сайта: /
Название сайта: Корпоративный сайт компании "Название компании"
URL сервера: www.site1.com
Путь к корневой папке веб-сервера для этого сайта: /home/www/site1/
```

Если DNS настроен таким образом, что ваш сайт отвечает на адрес http://site1.com, то в поле Доменное имя желательно указывать без www. Можно перечислить в этом поле с новой строки любое число доменных имен, по которым вы хотите, чтобы отвечал сайт (или уже отвечает).

Важно иметь в виду, что значения, указанные в поле Доменное имя, используются продуктом для распространения в указанные домены информации о посетителях по технологии переноса посетителей. Поэтому крайне желательно указывать полный список доменов, по которым может ответить сайт.

Очень важно не указывать в списке доменов сайты, которые не работают на данном экземпляре продукта. Указанный неправильно или несуществующий домен может не только замедлить работу пользователей, но и фактически не позволит перенести данные в сайты, работающие не на общем экземпляре продукта.

Аналогично настроим параметры второго сайта (www.site2.com/):

```
Название: site2
Доменное имя: site2.com
Папка сайта: /
Название сайта: Интернет-магазин компании "Название компании"
URL сервера: www.site2.com
Путь к корневой папке веб-сервера для этого сайта: /home/www/site2/
```

Обратите внимание, что для двух сайтов в параметре Папка сайта указано одинаковое значение: "/". Это связано с тем, что сайты обслуживаются разными "виртуальными серверами" (в терминологии Apache) у которых для размещения файлов использован разный каталог.

Также необходимо обратить внимание на параметр Путь к корневой папке веб-сервера для этого сайта. Для разных сайтов у него свое значение, взятое из параметра DocumentRoot настроек соответствующего "виртуального сервера" (см. ниже пример части файла httpd.conf настроек Apache).

У Битрикса есть [отдельный курс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=103&CHAPTER_ID=03987&LESSON_PATH=8799.3987) посвященный работе с многосайтовостью в котором описаны основные сценарии по работе и настройки. Читайте, выбирайте подходящий вариант и настраивайте.

Comment: Не подходит, многосайтовость платная. Всем хочется бесплатно. И, конечно же, многосайтовость была первым вариантом.

Comment: В каком месте она платная? Одну админку хоть на 500 сайтов никто не мешает использоваться. Разложите поддомены на поддиректории. Настройте правильный редиректы и файлы хостов. В админке создаете количество шаблонов по количество нужных поддоменов. Ставите условие для показа нужного шаблона. Только читать и думать уметь нужно. Под сайтом подразумевается размещение лицензии на другом сервере/хостинге. К тому же по новой политике лицензирования количество сайтов на лицензии неограничено с версии 18.0. Но ах да, никто же не оплачивает продление лицензии. Бесплатно только сыр в мышеловке.

Comment: Что-же, благодарю за разъяснение, буду пробовать. Что вы имеете ввиду под файлами хостов? файлы .htaccess?

Comment: в зависимости от способа реализации может понадобится создание/редактирование дополнительных vhost-файлов.

Comment: Ответы-ссылки у нас не приветствуются. Хорошо бы основное перенести в ответ.

Comment: Перенес основную информацию. Совсем кратко не получается.